# Global alias in zshrc file

Tags: command-line, terminal, zsh, alias

I am using the command line in a MacBookPro terminal, with zsh as the default profile.

I am trying to write a global alias to the `zshrc` in my home directory file but encounter a strange error.

If I write the alias text using `NANO` the file saves the new alias, however if I write the following in the command line, the `zshrc` file does not update to include the new alias.

MWE:

```
alias -g c="clear"
source ~/.zshrc
```

Any ideas on how to discover the problem?

Comment: I may be misreading your question, but the `source` command does not alter the contents of `~/.zshrc`. Instead it reads from the file, executing the commands in the file as if you had typed them on the command line. More info [here](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-source) and [here](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-_002e).

Answer (score 1):

Global aliases in Zsh are so aggressive that you’re replacing even the `c` in `~/.zshrc`. Your

```bsh
source ~/.zshrc
```

is interpreted as

```bsh
source ~/.zshrclear
```

You probably want a simple alias instead of a global alias. Try this instead:

```bsh
alias c='clear'
```

Comment: He probably wants a simple alias indeed, but the `c` would only be interpreted as a global alias if it's a token: surrounded by spaces, newline or other special chars.
For example, `echo c` would be interpreted as `echo clear` and output `clear`, but `echo cat` would be interpreted normally.